# How can git-fetch only download changes without adding/updating files?

Tags: git, git-pull, git-fetch

- Project.git is a remote git repo that has a staging branch
- Two developers are working on their own forks of project.git
- Both developers only interact with staging

#### Common to both developers

```
# Developer 1 & developer 2 add staging as follows
$ git clone myForkOfProject.git
$ git remote add live project.git
```

#### Developer 2 working on docs

```
[master] $ git branch docs
[master] $ git checkout docs
[docs] $ git add README 
[docs] $ git commit -m "pushing to live's staging from local's docs works" README
[docs] $ git push live docs:staging
```

#### Developer 1 working on bugfix, wants to selectively merge docs

Developer 1 wants to see selectively merge files from docs into his local `mybranch`

```
[master] git branch mybranch
[master] git checkout mybranch
[mybranch] $  git fetch live staging

# Checks to see if anything changed
[mybranch] $  git status -s ./
[mybranch] $

# Doesn't know what to merge since diff, status shows no change 

# Where as if developer1 did
[mybranch] $  git pull live staging
[mybranch] $  git status -s ./
A  README
```

#### What developer1 actually wanted

What developer1 wanted to do is only to fetch the last changes in staging into the working directory without automatically adding README.

How do I pull/fetch so that `git status -s ./` just downloads the changes

```
[mybranch] git *fetch changes from staging into mybranch 's working directory*
[mybranch] git status -s ./
[?] README
# This is what developer1 wants to see
# so that he can decide to 'git add README' manually
# here are the unsuccessful attempts to do the same

# Developer2 makes a commit, and does git push live docs:staging 
[mybranch] $ git fetch live staging
[mybranch] $ git pull live staging --no-commit --no-log --no-ff
```

The last option I have is to selectively call `git rm --cached README`, but I wonder if I'm missing something in the `git fetch`, `git merge` flow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git status` is for showing what's in your working directory. So after a `git fetch`, which doesn't change the working copy, of course you won't see anything.

`git show` is for showing changesets. So if you want to view the change before applying it, do `git show` (find the changes to examine with `git log live..mybranch` or the like; you could even use `git log --patch` to view the diffs inline with the commit notes).

However, in this workflow you say you specifically want to incorporate the changes into the working copy - but *not* to commit them.

You can do this in two steps: first, you `git merge` the changes in with yours. Then, you `git reset [revision]`, giving the revision you were at before the merge.

This will leave you with no staged changes, an unmoved `HEAD` (you reset back to the state before the merge, so it's been effectively reversed), and a working copy containing all the modifications before you did the `git merge`.

`git pull` is just a shorthand for `git fetch; git merge` or `git fetch; git rebase`, depending on your settings.

Comment: I think `git merge` followed by `git reset` would be better done using `git merge --squash` (possibly followed by `git reset <paths>` to unstage), which will avoid doing-and-undoing things. Also, "the revision you were at before the merge" can be obtained automatically by `@{1}` or (in the simple case) `HEAD@{1}`.

Comment: Thanks Borealid & Kevin.
Will use git fetch, then git show and git log to preview
followed by git merge  what finally git reset to unstage